# How to reload drives in Android

Tags: android, driver, reload

I have an app that is managing the Internet connection. Therefore I often enable and disable the wifi module. After few cycles the Wifi do not want to connect but according to the android settings the wifi module is enabled. -> In this case no matter how(my App or system settings) i try to connect nothing happens. 
The only solution is to restart the phone. With all drivers reloaded it works again.

Since restart is something you do not want to do, I would like to reload the drivers.

Is there a way to do that? Where to find the right driver ("/sys/module/tiwlan_drv" ?)?

Thx Ivo

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with devices where the wifi seems to shut off even though it is reporting as on. I've always been able to fix by toggling it off and back on again.

P.S. an issue that I've seen related to this: When the device disconnected, but showing wifi enabled, if I load a web page in the browser I'll get the page not found screen.

Once I flip flop the wifi to fix the connection if I go back to the browser and try to load the same page I still get page not found. The browser is caching a broken version of the page =x. Only way I've found to fix is go in to settings and force stop the browser, or wait for a while.

Comment: In my case only a restart helps. The described situation is been reproduced on over 5 deferent devices(mostly htc). Is there a way to reload drives without root access (i really doubt it).